# TFS command for switching workspace

Tags: command-line, tfs, tf-cli

Is there a command to switch the active workspace from tf.exe ?
I have searched [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/workspace-command) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/workspaces-command).
But I do recall, I've seen it some time ago.

Comment: What's the detail mean of switching the active workspace? Did you mean you want to achieve the function same as changing workspace in Visual Studio from  the arrow or just want to modify/update the workspace mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to change a workspace, you could not be able to do this through `tf.exe` command line. You should active you workspace window **in Visual Studio**:

- In Visual Studio,click Source Control Explore.
- From the Workspace dropdown select "*Workspaces...*"
- The Workspace window appears
- Click the WorkSpace name in Workspace window
- From the popup list choose the Workspace name you want.

---

If you want to modify/update the workspace mapping, you could use [`tf workfold`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/workfold-command) command, sample as below:

```
c:\projects>tf workfold /collection:http://servername:8080/tfs/collectionname /workspace:workspacename  $/projects/project_one C:\DifferentWorkfold
```

The above example maps the folder `C:\DifferentWorkfold` to the Team Foundation version control server folder `$/projects/project_one` and replaces the previous workspace mapping for the `$/projects/project_one` Team Foundation version control server folder.

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to change the workspace without opening the VS. Interesting why this wasn't implemented.

Comment: @jasondinAlt Sorry, not sure about this, however most of the `tf.exe` command support with `[/workspace:workspacename]` argument which could specifies the name of the workspace to work in. Seems like to be an option to switch workspace, however not be able to do the same thing as Visual Studio do from  the Workspace dropdown in source control  explore.